# Creating simple counter of letters

Tags: python, counter

So I coded a super simple counter for returning ratio of letters:

```
def hasnoe(word):
    count = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter == 'e':
            count += 1.0
    ratio = count / (len(word))
    return ratio

hasnoe('eeeeeeheif')
```

But when I try it out, the computer returns no value - what is up?

Comment: Your edit to your post just completely changed the question. As currently written, your code produces expected behavior.

Comment: `s = 'eeeeeeheif'; print s.count('e') / float(len(s))`

Comment: Python2 or Python3? It's important because `/` works differently

Answer (score 3):

You cannot return more than one time from a function. You currently return `count` after the very first letter you loop over, so it can only be `0` or `1`.

All you have to do to fix this is remove `return count`

```
def hasnoe(word):
    count = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter == 'e':
            count += 1.0
    ratio = count/(len(word))
    return ratio

>>> hasnoe('eeeeeeheif')
0.7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> s = 'eeeeeeheif'
>>> c = Counter(s)
>>> c
Counter({'e': 7, 'i': 1, 'h': 1, 'f': 1})
>>> den = float(len(s))
>>> freq = dict((k, v/den) for k, v in c.iteritems())
>>> freq
{'i': 0.1, 'h': 0.1, 'e': 0.7, 'f': 0.1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code you return twice

```
 def hasnoe(word):
        count = 0
        for letter in word:
            if letter == 'e':
                count += 1.0
        ratio = count/(len(word))
        return ratio

    hasnoe('eeeeeeheif')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're best bet is going to be return a Tuple if you want both numbers.

```
def hasnoe(word):
    count = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter == 'e':
            count += 1.0
    ratio = count/(len(word))
    return ratio, count

ratio, count = hasnoe('eeeeeeheif')
```